# Is it possible to use datepart in datediff?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to use datepart in datediff

```
  SELECT   datediff (YEAR,2015 ,(datepart(YEAR,Person.DateOfBirth))) AS Exp from Person
```

please help me

Comment: `DateDiff`  expects datediff(Year,startingdatetime,enddatetime) and you are only specifying `2015` as startdatetime which is not a valid datetime

Comment: i would like use datepart in datediff

Comment: What is your actual requirement here?

Answer (score 0):

The arguments for datediff should be dates, for example:

```
datediff(year, '20150101', Person.DateOfBirth)
```

When using year, please remember that it tracks the change of year, so it's not suitable for calculating age, for example

```
select datediff(year, '20150101', '20150201')
```

Returns 0, but

```
select datediff(year, '20141231', '20150201')
```

returns 1.

Comment: i would like use  datepart in datediff

Comment: If you take datepart, then it's just 2 integers. you should use just minus for that.

Comment: 2015 - datepart(year. Person.DateOfBirth)

Answer (score 0):

yes,
but the formation like this..

```
datediff(result In(Year/Month/Day),toDate,Fromdate)
```

> '2015' in datediff is '2015-01-01'

try: `select CAST('2015' as date)`

```
SELECT datediff(YEAR,'2015',Person.DateOfBirth) AS Exp from Person--result in year 
SELECT datediff(Month,'2015',Person.DateOfBirth) AS Exp from Person--result in month 
SELECT datediff(Day,'2015',Person.DateOfBirth) AS Exp from Person--result in day
```